# FFmpeg adds an extra aac sequence header when there's no audio

Tags: ffmpeg

My IP Camera doesn't support audio. I got `rtsp.flv` by executing

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://** -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -f flv -y rtsp.flv`

This is the flv structure:
[rtsp.flv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EiHF.png) (note: `audio=0`)

Then I got `rtmp.flv` by executing two commands:

- `ffmpeg -i rtsp://** -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -f flv  rtmp://**1`

and

- `ffmpeg -i rtmp://**1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv -y rtmp.flv`.

This is the output flv structure: [rtmp.flv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT9BS.png)

**My question is :**

Why does the output flv structure `rtmp.flv` have `audio=1` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequence is a little hard to follow.  i.e, you output to rtsp://**1 but then reference (presumably) the same output with rt**m**p://**1

Irrespective of all that, if you don't want an audio track, use this on the final sequence;

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://**1 -vcodec copy -an -f flv -y rtmp.flv
```

From the FFmpeg man:

> **Audio Options**
>
> ```
>    -an (output)
>        Disable audio recording.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your help